# Java using an array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm new to Java so please be gentle...

Consider the following `ShoppingList Class`:

```
public class ShoppingList {
...
    public ItemPrices[] getSortedPrices(){
        //do sorting stuff here etc
        return ret.toArray(new ItemPrices[0]);
    }
}
```

And now I have another class called `Hello`:

```
public class Hello {
...
    private Groceries createGroceries() {
    ...
         pricearray[] =  ShoppingList.ItemPrices[] //????
    ...
    }
}
```

I want to assign the array pricearray I've created to equal to ItemPrices array returned in the method.

However I'm not getting what I want, what's the correct way to doing this?

Comment: How is possible that ItemPrices[] is a double?. You need to read some books...

Comment: I think you accidentally your question.

Comment: Ooops, copied wrong code sorry.

Comment: This a very, very specific programming issue, with little or no value to others. I can only recommend that you buy a book and read about types, arrays and constructors...

Comment: You're a beginner so I don't want to see rude. But there are so many things wrong with the question that I'm not sure where to start. `double pricearray =  ShoppingList.ItemPrices[]` will never work because both types on each side of the `=` have to match. This might get you closer: `ItemPrices[] prices = new ShoppingList().getSortedPrices()`. You should probably read up some more on types and basic Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the method `getSortedPrices` is a static method, you need to call it from an instance of the `ShoppingList` class, so you should create an instance as follows

```
public class Hello {
...
    private Groceries createGroceries() {
    ...
        ShoppingList sList = new ShoppingList();
        PriceList [] pricearray =  sList.getSortedPrices() //you call a method by its name, not return type.
    ...
    }
}
```

also, I dont see how

> (ItemPrices[] is a double).

is it supposed to be an array of doubles, or an array of instance of the class `ItemPrices`? 
if its supposed to be an array of doubles, you need to do this:

```
public class ShoppingList {
...
    public double[] getSortedPrices(){
        //do sorting stuff here etc
        return new double[n] // n is the length of the array
    }
}
```

and the line

`PriceList [] pricearray =  sList.getSortedPrices()`

should be

`double [] pricearray =  sList.getSortedPrices()`

Comment: Thanks, it's an array of doubles. Eclipse is still giving me an error saying that it doesn't "see" where ShoppingList class is so it can't call `ShoppingList()`. Both of these are in to different .java files (ShoppingList.java and Hello.java). Thanks for bearing with my mistakes!

Comment: @meiryo if they are in different packages, import `ShoppingList` class from that package, and make sure class name is spelled correctly with the right cases.

Answer (score 1):

Without focusing on your other problems, you've got to do something like

```
ShoppingList sl = new ShoppingList();
ItemPrices[] pricearray =  sl.getSortedPrices();
```

but this requires you to know types, constructors, arrays, how to call a method and a lot of other things!